# Select records from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have these 3 tables with the following columns:

1. `employee`: empId (PK), hireDate, jobTitle, department (FK), status (FK)
2. `status`: statusId, statusDesc
3. `department`: departmentId, deptName, supervisorId, deptHeadId

What I want to do is to display the following columns: `hireDate`, `jobTitle`, `deptName`, `statusDesc`

The problem that I'm encountering is that it does not display the `statusDesc` and `deptName` records.

Here's my code/sql query:

```
$empId = $_GET['empId'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT e.empId, e.hireDate, e.jobTitle, d.deptName, s.statusDesc 
                        FROM employee e , department d, status s
                        WHERE e.department = d.departmentId AND e.status = s.statusId AND e.empId = $empId;");
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't included the problem. The following code does not display the deptName and statusDesc records.

Comment: Does this employee have any department or status? I mean is there any data against the employee table in department and status table?

Comment: Yes it has department and status.

Comment: Are the fields `deptName` and `statusDesc` empty or you dont get any rows?

Comment: The hireDate and jobTitle shows records but the deptName and statusDesc are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$empId = $_GET['empId'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT e.empId, e.hireDate, e.jobTitle, d.deptName, s.statusDesc 
                        FROM employee e 
                        INNER Join department d on e.department = d.departmentId
                        INNER Join status s on e.status = s.statusId
                        WHERE e.empId = $empId;");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query, providing the employee has a valid department and a valid status - if the columns are blank then it is because the descriptor fields in the department and status tables are empty (deptName and statusDesc).

Comment: I already checked my deptName and statusDesc columns and both contains descriptor fields. I'm wondering why the records aren't showing up.